# Auto Layout intrinsic content size to fill screen

Tags: ios, uikit, autolayout

I have a view that presents the device's camera feed using `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`. I plan that this view will fill the device's screen and leave some space at the top and bottom.

**Q1** Does it make sense for my view to implement `intrinsicContentSize` and have this provide the size it will be when it is scaled so that it just fits the screen? Or am I misunderstanding auto layout and `intrinsicContentSize`?

**Q2** Can the implementation of `intrinsicContentSize` in my `UIView` subclass make use of `[[self window] screen]`? This will work if the layout system asks the view calls `intrinsicContentSize` once the view is attached to a screen. If the call occurs before this point, the view won't know the screen to which it will be attached, and this will fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't use `intrinsicContentSize` for this in the end. It seems more simpler and more flexible to allow the `CameraView` to have its size controlled in my storyboard.

My `CameraView`, a `UIView` subclass has an `aspectRatioConstraint` property that it sets up and updates in its `updateConstraints` override:

```
-(void) updateConstraints
{
  if(!_aspectRatioConstraint)
  {
    const CGSize videoSize = [self videoSize];
    NSLayoutConstraint *const aspectConstraint =
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: self
                                 attribute: NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                 relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem: self
                                 attribute: NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                multiplier: videoSize.height / videoSize.width
                                  constant: 0];
    [self setAspectRatioConstraint: aspectConstraint];
    [self addConstraint: aspectConstraint];
  }

  [super updateConstraints];
}
```

(The constraint's ratio is determined by what the camera device reports back in `[self videoSize]`)

In the storyboard I also set up an aspect ratio constraint on the camera's view, but I check the `placeholder` option on the constraint so that it is removed at build time. I set this up to be 4:3 which may or may not be the same as the real camera – it's just to give me about the right frame during view layout.

I make the `CameraView` fill the screen by setting a constraint on its width in the storyboard.